# Backup sails-disk data

Tags: sails.js

I'm working on a sails app that I'll only use locally, so I'm using the `sails-disk` default for persistence.  I would like to be able to backup and restore the data I put in there, though.  Is this possible?

I didn't see anything in the waterline docs about working with the store other than via the API.  I can write some sails code to export/import a dump, but if there's already something available or a standard way of doing this I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sails-disk`, by default, stores data in `.tmp/localDiskDb.db` file inside your Sails project.

One way to take backup/restore is make copy of that file.